# Using JPA objects in parallel streams with Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, java-stream

I'm working on spring-boot application with JPA. In the code I found a really suspicious part which does something like (simplified example, the code otherwise contains a lot of clutter):

```
entityRepository.findAll().parallel() // The findAll returns already a stream, it's a CrudRepository from Spring
   .filter (...)
   .map(e -> {
      OtherDbObject other = service.getOtherDbObjectBasedOn(e);
      boolean hasSomething = other.getProperties().stream() //properties is fetch type EAGER @OneToMany collection in OtherDbObject
        .filter(...)
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent();

      ...
   })
```

It seems the `parallel` is causing whole lot of troubles including errors like:

```
jvm 1    | org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: bug adding collection twice
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addCollection(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:857)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addInitializedCollection(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:896)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:242)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:739)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:924)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:149)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
jvm 1    |      at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:277)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1821)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:408)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:497)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
...
```

I would say it's at least suspicious to do something DB related in `parallel` stream but I can't any evidence that it should be avoided.

I would appreciate any help in either explaining the error or finding solid evidence which proves that parallel streams with JPA inside are unsafe.

Comment: The `EntityManager` is thread bound... parallel uses multiple threads, but the object is still tied to the first `EntityManager` (those pesky proxies), now when you try to persist it in the other thread you suddenly get errors on stuff being maintained by multiple `EntityManagers`...

Comment: @M.Deinum: I feel you are right but I would love to understand this in detail. Are you saying that entity loaded in one thread is generally unsafe to be used in other threads (even though it has only EAGER collections)? If so would you mind to explain what exactly happens so the entity "gets tight" to two EntityManagers? It's really interesting and I would love to understand. Any pointer to documentation explaining this will be also much appreciated. Also feel free to add this as answer so I can accept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is too little code to be specific, but you have a service and that is querying, so I assume that is using a JPA repository to. That is going to open a new entity manager and you probably using the passed in entity as a query parameter (and maybe there is even a relation between both entities).

Comment: @M.Deinum you should convert your comment to an answer